# How to convert a list in a string ("[foo]") to a list ([foo]) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, csv

Right now I have a dataset where each line is a string in the form:

```
"[6.43736, 23, {}, [], '']"
```

I want to convert it into a list, but i cant for the life of me figure out of to do it. The preferred output would look like this:

```
[6.43736, 23, {}, [], '']
```

For each line in the csv file.

Comment: "Right now i have a dataset where each line is a string in the form:" What generated such a string? Somewhere, someone decided "let me save this string representation of a Python data structure in a csv file and pretend it is serialization". It isn't. Use a pre-built serialization format, like JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is good for safely evaluating strings that look like numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, bools, None, and strings:

```
>>> s = "[6.43736, 23, {}, [], '']"
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
[6.43736, 23, {}, [], '']
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply! However, this does not change the string to a list, which means I still can't index it.

Comment: @Bogehave yes, *it does if that string is exactly what you posted*.

Comment: literal_eval _should_ return a list in this case, which can be indexed. Are you assigning the result to anything? It won't alter `s` in-place; you'll need to do something like `seq = ast.literal_eval(s); print(seq[0])`.

Comment: My bad, i think it may be an issue that im trying to do within a csv file? When i run this code i get <class 'str'> for each output:

`def sprog_csv(csv_file):

    with open(csv_file) as f:

        for item in f:
            seq = ast.literal_eval(item)
            print(type(seq))`

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the structure of the csv file. Wild guess: Maybe the string has an additional layer of quote marks. try `seq = ast.literal_eval(ast.literal_eval(item)))`

Comment: You are 100% correct, thank you so much for the help Kevin!